# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'copy_reg\r'

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, pickle

I am trying to execute a python code in my Windows Machine where I have imported pickle and I have loaded the file but for some reason, it is giving this error called ModuleNotFound and I don't know what does pickle has to do anything with 'copy_reg\r'

Here goes my code:

```
from six.moves import cPickle
def openfile(basename):
    with open(os.path.join(DIR_PATTERNS, basename), 'rb') as fh:
        return cPickle.load(fh)
        #return open(os.path.join(DIR_PATTERNS, basename), 'rb')

HAVE_FSAs = openfile("HAVE_FSAs.pickle")
```

Here goes the error:

```
HAVE_FSAs = cPickle.load(openfile("HAVE_FSAs.pickle"))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'copy_reg\r'
```

I have already tried `import pickle as cPickle` but it did not work for me. All the variables are declared so it can't be that as well and moreover, I do not understand why is it giving ModuleNotFound

Comment: you are probably trying to load python2 pickle in python3

Answer (score 0):

python3 have copyreg, no copy_reg . so you can correct Source Code, for example, you need delete code:

```
import copy_reg
```

then, you must replace:

```
import copyreg
```